# can all HTML snippets be used in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

can any HTML snippet which is valid and follows good practice be returned from a React component or are there limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React creates a virtual DOM of HTML elements. So, any html snippet will work with react. However, you may have to change some attribute name such as, **class** will be named as **className** in react. Your app will still work if you don't change those attribute names, it will just give you warnings.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there are also some tags such as `<br>` or `<hr>` that require to be closed at end `<br/>` `<hr/>`